# Disable comments when creating a page from script (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm creating a simple child page in a Google site using Apps Script.

```js
function createLibraryEntry(sessionObject){

  var site = SitesApp.getSite("student.vis.ac.at", "professional-development-library");
  var library = site.getChildByName('library');

  var sessionPage = library.createWebPage(
                                          "session1234",
                                          "session1234",
                                          "<h1>Session 1234</h1>"
                                          );                              
}
```

Having read the documentation and done a fair amount of searching I'm unable to find a way to disable comments or attachments, on creation, for the new page. Neither can I find a way to set them on the page, by script, after creation (this can be achieved in the sites UI through 'page settings').

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: It's extremely rare that there is any method that's neither documented nor supported by auto-complete in the editor. When you've put the effort into the hunt, and come up empty, it's usually because the method does not exist. Time for a work-around. Have you tried [`createPageFromTemplate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/site#createPageFromTemplate(String,String,Page))?

Comment: Thanks @Mogsdad, I had already started looking at the createPageFromTemplate() method as a workaround, nice to be reassured I hadn't missed something!

Comment: I'm proposing to remove the google-apps-for-education tag as it looks to be irrelevant to the question.